# Adding www to urls with url rewrite

Tags: regex, iis-7, url-rewriting, url-rewrite-module

I've found this code to add the www to urls without it using url rewrite.

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <clear />
        <rule name="WWW Rewrite" enabled="true">
            <match url="(.*)" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" negate="true" pattern="^www\.([.a-zA-Z0-9]+)$" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.{HTTP_HOST}/{R:0}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

But it seems to not work of the url has a '-' in it, such as scotts-cleaners.com.

That returns www.www.scotts-cleaners.com.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Simply add `-` to the pattern:

```
<add input="{HTTP_HOST}" negate="true" pattern="^www\.([.a-zA-Z0-9-]+)$" />
```

Since hyphen and alphanumeric constitute the only allowed characters in a domain name, your pattern should now work for all URLs.

Comment: Unfortunately, it still doesn't work.  That certainly seems correct to me.

Answer (score 0):

```
pattern="^www\.([.a-zA-Z0-9-]+)$"
```

apparently hyphens don't need escaping in regex ^^

Comment: You don't escape the hyphen within a bracket expression (range).  Use `"^www\.([.a-zA-Z0-9-]+)$" instead.